# No css work is visible after loading the static file in django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates, static-linking

I have just started learning django and got stuck in one place with the 'static' step
i did all the steps of static like load static ,STATIC_DIR,ROOT and also wrote in all the image,.js and also in the css line bt still i could only view the html text and not the temp.
let me know what to do pls

Comment: Try to open the page in incognito/private mode. Might be a problem of cache.

Comment: Also you should try to debug using 'Inspect' and check if you are able to open the link...

Comment: Hey thankyou for responding!

Comment: It is still not working

Comment: Can you please update your question and paste the snippet of the configuration and code? Also have you tried debugging your Source file? Just view as source and check if the link for JS and CSS is opening.